# Reference Request : 3-regular graphs are not uniquely hamiltonian.

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, planar-graphs, hamiltonicity

I have found the following articles which relates somewhat to what I am searching for but completely so I need help finding more references, if not similar to what I have then anything closely related to it.

1. [Planar Graphs, Regular Graphs, Bipartite Graphs and
   Hamiltonicity](https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/20/ocr-ajc-v20-p111.pdf) :
2. [Hamiltonicity of planar cubic multigraphs](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82707484.pdf)
3. [A Lower Bound for the Smallest Uniquely Hamiltonian Planar Graph
   with Minimum Degree Three](https://www.ac.tuwien.ac.at/files/tr/ac-tr-19-007.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W. T. Tutte “on Hamiltonian circuits”. J. London Math. Soc. (1946). This contains a proof that in a cubic graph the number of Hamiltonian circuits on an edge is even.